# Setting DS and using AH = 0Ah in DOS

Tags: assembly, x86-16, dos

So I'm trying to get user input in DOS assembly, but I can't seem to wrap my head around how to set DS and DX in a way so that the buffered input interrupt writes to the right place. Here is the code of my main file:

```
BITS 16
org 0x100

Start:

; SNIP

mov dx, Name
call GetString

; SNIP

Exit:
mov ax, 0x4c00
int 0x21

Name:
        db 33
        db 0
        times 255 db 0
```

And here is my GetString procedure which is from another file. I've intended for it to expect DX to be set before the function is called and then leave DX pointing to the start of the actual string:

```
GetString:
push ax
push bx
; syscall
mov ax, 0x0a
int 0x21
mov bx, dx ; move buffer to adressing register
inc bx ; get number of chars read 
movzx si, [bx] ; put bx's value (numbers of chars read) into si
inc bx ; get actual string buffer
add si, bx ; number of chars read + buffer = last byte
mov byte [si], '$' ; $ terminate
mov dx, bx
pop bx
pop ax
ret
```

I don't seem to get why it doesn't work. Am I supposed to set DS to something and if yes to what?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not  a good problem description. What happens, and how do you know it's wrong?

Comment: Looks like ".com" executable, where all data and code and stack reside in single segment, with code starting at `0x0100`. So at the start of code you can do `push cs` `pop ds` to copy `cs` into `ds`, which should work for ".com" (not for ".exe").

Comment: In some assemblers you can use `MOV AX,@DATA; MOV DS,AX` when assembling an .exe file.

Comment: Also the x86 assembler I used required `mov dx, OFFSET Name`.

Comment: Sorry doesn't work is a bad description. The program basically dies when the interrupt in `GetString` gets called. Adding push cs and pop ds makes the program not crash but it still doesn't stop to ask for input.

Comment: Compiling it as an exe file doesn't change anything...

Comment: You can't code in Assembly without debugger. With debugger you would probably ultimately notice, that at the `int 21h` supposed to take input, which does not, the `ah` is not set correctly (although it would probably take several tries, until your brain would finally admit the `ax` being `000A` is not the same as `0A00`, just very close to it). Or after few tries delete that part and write it from scratch (probably without typo second time).

Comment: I did use a debugger and that's how I knew it dies precisely on the int call. I just thought it did because I didn't set up DS properly and it wrote/read to somewhere where it  wasn't supposed to.

Comment: There is a companion debugging method where you read each line of the code, and think "mmm does this line do what I want?" Knowing where the fault occurred, would have made this easy. In the days of line printers (where you could read the text as it was being printed) doing a listing was also an invaluable method of "breaking" the thoughts and assumptions.

Comment: Will keep it in mind and use it in the future. Thanks everyone for the replies!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `GetString` you have

```
mov ax, 0x0a
int 0x21
```

This loads `ah` with `00` (`al` with `0ah`) and calls interrupt `21h` function `00h` which is "terminate program".

If you meant to call function `0ah` "buffered STDIN input" you need

```
mov ah, 0x0a
int 0x21
```

along with `DS:DX` pointing to the initiliased buffer, as you have.